# How to power-up PSU from Proliant DL185 without mobo?

Tags: hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

I have an old Proliant DL185 G5 server with a 447325-001 Power supply backplane. Two connectors seem to be interesting, one is what looks like an ATX-power connector and connecting green to GND spins up the fans of the attached 449840-002. The second is marked RPS, is a small connector and has 12 pins.

The issue is, no power is output on any pins.
Looking at the service manual for DL185 it seems to be that the RPS connector attaches to 'MT9 Redundant Power Supply Management Interface Connector'

I have searched for any description of a RPS pinout without success.
Do I need to use this connector to get power from the PSU? How can I get power from the PSU without a motherboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect PIN 15 & PIN 16 (PWN_ON/Green to GND/Black) of the ATX (like?) header

[image]

```
   .___.              
 1-|O O|--13           
 2-|O O|--14           
 3-|O O|--15           
 4-|O O|--16           
 5-|O O|--17           
 6-|O O|]-18           
 7-|O O|]-19           
 8-|O O|--20           
 9-|O O|--21           
10-|O O|--22
11-|O O|--23
12-|O O|--24
   '---'
```

And
Connect PIN 7 (Black/White) & PIN 3 (Green/White) of the RPS/MT9 Redundant Power Supply Management Interface Connector

[image]

```
   .___.              
 1-|O O|---7           
 2-|O O|---8           
 3-|O O|]--9           
 4-|O O|]-10           
 5-|O O|--11           
 6-|O O|--12           
   '---'
```

The attached pictures use a 26-Ohm resistor to connect the pins as that was what I had at hand, I assume it works with a paperclip too.

[Image of AC-063-A PSU backplane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmpHq.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I’d like to leave something more for the future.

I had same  problem with very similar backplane: AC-063-2 A

This one have addidional pins on RPS connector. I figured it out:

[image: RPS connector]

Answer (score 1):

Good day!
I stumbled upon your post while looking for a HP DL180 G6 Server power supply launcher. Basket AC-063-2 A.
Your launch method, for some reason, did not fit. He began to hiccup with the method of "scientific poking". I found that the power supply is triggered by a jumper on the RPS connector (16 pins), between 1 (green) and 14 (brown / white).
Maybe someone will come in handy.

Comment: Alexey, I've fount this article after building my system in 2021. I took DL180 G6 case with Power distribution board/ backplane AC-063-2 A and with native coolers and mounted Supermicro_X9DRD-7LN4F motherboard (it has sufficient number of PCIe slots). I was fortunate - somebody already connected a jumper on the RPS connector (16 pins), between 1 (green) and 14 (brown / white) like in post above. I use common slot PSU 1200 W from another proliant server.

Comment: But to boot this system I found the only following way - remotely using IPMI. Via IPMI it's possible to start server, restart server. But shutdown doesn't work - shutting down Windows 10 shuts down the OS but coolers continue running. short circuiting PWR pins on motherboard doesn't start the system - only via IPMI.

Comment: Would be great to integrate HP PSU and Supermicro motherboard completely.
Another goal is to increase wattage of AC-063-2 A power backplane - it has limit: 62.5 A in +12 V line. But it allows to insert 2 common slot PSU 1200 W each. I want to use second free slot in the case and to add second 1200 W PSU. How to modify power backplane? Besides - I can get second AC-063-2 A backplane - but I think the only one backplane is sufficient for modification. Second PSU gives +12 V already - the problem is to synchronize 2 PSU in another not standard for backplane way.